# For - of loop with async/await together with pool.query for postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, node-postgres

I was looking at this other SO thread here: [async/await with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) and wanted to do something similar with my code but unfortunately I can't see what the error is.

The `groups` value here is an array taken from `req.body.allGroups`. It doesn't seem to be performing any inserts at all into my `my_groups` postgres table.

```
app.post("/create-group", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const groups = req.body.allGroups; 
    console.log(groups);

    for (const group of groups) {   
      console.log(group.groupName);
      let newGroup = await pool.query(       
        "INSERT INTO my_groups (id, group_name) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING group_id",
            [ 99, group.groupName ]
      );
      res.json(newGroup.rows[0]);
    }

  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err.messasge);
  }
})
```

**>>> UPDATED:**

I have updated my code based on queries below and have also added console.log messages.

The console.log output after running the above updated code is as follows:

```
[
  {
    groupName: 'G1'
  },
  {
    groupName: 'G2'
  }
]
G1
undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure `req.body.allGroups` contains a Promise? It's not impossible but quite unusual to see await on a property rather than on a function.

Comment: When you set res.json doesn’t that send a response back to the user, effectively ending the loop after one iteration

Comment: What's the actual problem? That `pool.query("INSERT ...")` doesn't create new entries? Then why the title?

Comment: 30k (hence I guess at least some experience) and yet only a _"it doesn't seem to..."_? Check with the debugger, add `console.log()`s, ...

Comment: "*I can't see what the error is*" - we can't see the log output either. Please be more specific about what doesn't work and what error messages you get. The "await in a loop" is fine per se.

Comment: @James It doesn't end the loop. It just causes exceptions from the second iteration onwards.

Comment: @Bergi Have updated my post and also provided sample output. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bergi I'm actually not getting any error just the output provided above and no actual inserts into postgres table occuring at all.

Comment: The `undefined` would presumably come from the logged `err.messasge`. Try logging `err.message` (or just the whole `err`) instead.

Comment: @Bergi by just console logging the whole `err` I managed to track that the issue was in fact a foreign key constraint violation that I have on the `my_groups` table. All good now and works a treat. I will place this as part of answering my own question.

Comment: @Bergi - my only other question is, what is the best way to use `res.json(newGroup.rows[0]);` ?

Comment: @tonyf Collect them into an array, respond with the array after the loop? I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

1. you shouldnt do res.json() in the for loop.
   try putting it one ligne below, and adapt it, as the newGroup variable wont be reachable.
2. await req.body.allGroups is not usual. unless your library needs this await should not be used.
3. anyway, can you try to console.log(groups) before the loop to confirm that the data exist please. If yes, you have a problem in you pool.
4. the catch part should do something like res.send('Error')
   or better : next(err);
   if you don't, the browser connexion will stay hanging.

Comment: Have updated my post and also provided sample output. Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please assist of where to place `res.json()` as outside of the loop, the `newGroup` variable is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

Some output would've been helpful. But i suggest you to debug the value of groups, i believe it stays empty, so the loop never runs, that's why nothing happens and you may not be getting may error.
Also, await is supposed to be put in front of promise for which we want to wait. So make sure `req.body.allGroups` is a promise.

Comment: Have updated my post and also provided sample output.

Answer (score 0):

By just console logging the whole err I managed to track that the issue was in fact a foreign key constraint violation that I have on the my_groups table.

All good now.